# Adding RESTful Web services from database

Tags: rest, jpa, netbeans

Sometimes when I add RESTful Web services from database in my NetBeans' Web Application project, the JPA Controller and REST Facade are not creating, only the entity class is added. 
Do you know what can be the reason?

@EDIT:
I just found out that ther is showing some exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.netbeans.modules.websvc.rest.codegen.EntityResourcesGenerator.generate(EntityResourcesGenerator.java:175)
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.websvc.rest.wizard.EntityResourcesIterator$1.run(EntityResourcesIterator.java:130)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1411)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:1991)
```

@EDIT 2:

I am mapping table by table, because the database is quite big and when I try to add all at once something goes wrong and the REST Facades are not created. So when I create a new REST service from a table that is not connected with others - everything is ok. But when the table is connected with others that I already added earlier and they need to be updated - only the entity class is created, there is no REST Facade.

Comment: What tool are you using?

Comment: NetBeans 7.1.2, sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Since ver. 6.something, Controller classes are not created anymore because the implementation uses the JAX-RS annotations. But definitely yes, you should see NetBeans creating the EntityFacadeREST classes for each entity

Comment: Wow! You are crashing NetBeans! It's probably a bug in NB. I suggest to try with ver 7.2, and if it happens again, [file a bug](http://netbeans.org/community/issues.html). However that must be something really weird, because that wizard is used since years. Either you want help here or there, remember to add all the details (db structure, datasource definition, etc..)

Comment: I tried with NB 7.2, but still the same. In general when I try to map all the database at once something goes wrong and any REST Facade is created (the database is very big). So I am mapping table by table, seems to be ok, but for some of them there is just created entity class and this error of NB shows in the right bottom corner.